# Recreate Item Content Type

Tags: 2010

I've started to hit this error again and again.

1. I have a site.
2. I define a content type that extends Item ( Item in turn extends System ).
3. I Save the site as a template
4. I recreate the site a couple of times
5. I deactivate the template and delete it
6. I recreate the tempalte with the previous name from the previous Site with the new modifications

Then I start noticing that my title, which I had previously set to be hidden is visible. I start looking at the Item Content Type. When I get there I see that it no longer has a Title column ?

It's very frustrating to say the least and I don't know how to recreate it or how to make this not happen anymore.

Any help or guidance ?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why the scenario I was portraying happens however it's possible to download the template and import it into VS.

In VS change the Title property on Item ( or on any Content Type you have inheriting from Item and is missbehaving ) to have `Required="FALSE"` and optionally set `Hidden="true"`.

I'll leave the question open for a bit longer maybe someone else will be able to better enlighten me.